# RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to fetch messages and users at the same time for showing current user's conversations and who he/she talked with. The problem is whatever I did, I keep getting this error. Currently there is two message doc in the collection. It fetches from the messages with no problem but it can not read the "users" collection second time.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final userID = user!.uid;
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .where('senderID', isEqualTo: userID)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("no data at the moment");
        }
        return Column(children: [
            ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print('another user id:');
                  print(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['anotherUserID']);
                  return ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('users')
                              .where('userID',
                                  isEqualTo: snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                                      ['anotherUserID'])
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context, snap) {
                            if (!snap.hasData) return const Text("Loading...d");
                            print(snap.data!.docs[index]['profileImage']);//it prints the information
                            print(snap.data!.docs[index]['name']);        //of first chat but second one  
                            print(snap.data!.docs[index]['username']);     //doesn't printed
                            print(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['lastMessage']);
                            print(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['timestamp']);
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    snap.data!.docs[index]['profileImage']),
                              ),
                              title: Text(snap.data!.docs[index]['name']),
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                  );
                }),
      
        ]);
      
      },
    );
```

And this is how screen look like:[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ6WR.jpg)

Comment: You are passing same index everywhere but length of users list will be different from length of messages list that is why this error is showing. Can you share the json response?

Comment: Hi, but I'm fetching only the users with same id in my messages collection. So, users and messages must be always equal. Can you send me a link to how will i get json response? I couldn't find it in the web. Thank you. (Note: in messages collection, every doc have only one "senderID" not more than one.)